# In ie8 jquery error(The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

In ie8 jquery error(The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object)

this error only coming in ie8 in chrome and firefox working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('#otp').bind("cut copy paste", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('#dropdown').on('click', function () {
            $('.dropdownwrap').slideToggle();
        });

    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: If you are using jquery 2.* then it will not work in ie8, you need to use version 1.*: https://jquery.com/browser-support/

Answer (score 2):

In latest versions of chrome and FF [and maybe Safari as well] '$' is natively supported.

IE 9 does not support this natively, hence you get the error you stated.

I would highly suggest to include jQuery in your page and try the code again.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

include this jquery in your page